# The reverse of a number

Tags: java

Have the user enter an integer n between 100 and 999. If the integer does not satisfy the given criteria, the program should display an error message and terminate. If the number is in the correct range, the program will compute a number K that represents the reverse of the entered number. The program will display number k. Ex: Please enter a number between 100 and 1000. 71 Your number is not in the correct range, good bye. Please enter a number between 100 and 1000. 679 The reverse is: 976 any help is greatly appreciated thank uuuuu. this is also to be done in the SIMPLEST way possible. heres what I have so far:

```
public class ReverseOfClass 
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
    { 

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.print("Enter an integer between 100-999: "); 
        int integer = in.nextInt(); 


        if (integer > 999) 
        {   
            System.out.print("Your number is not in the correct range, good bye"); 
        } 
        else if (integer < 100) 
        { 
            System.out.print("Your number is not in the correct range, good bye"); 
        }
```

im not sure where to implement the part about the numbers between 100-999 or the reverse of them

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't just a code-writing service. You should give this a try, and if a specific thing doesn't work as you expect, you should search the topic and then, if you still can't find the answer, ask here. If your problem is that you don't know where to start, that's too broad for this site; you should do your teacher, TA or (if allowed by your teacher) fellow students for help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Give this a try:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter an integer between 100-999: ");
    int integer = in.nextInt();
    int reverse = 0;

    if (integer >= 100 && integer <= 999) {
        while(integer != 0)
        {
            reverse = reverse * 10;
            reverse = reverse + integer%10;
            integer = integer/10;
        }

        System.out.println("Reverse of the number is " + reverse);
    } else {
        System.out.print("Your number is not in the correct range, good bye");
    }

}
```

Comment: no worries, but you should try it yourself also :-)

Comment: Why would they try it for themselves if people on SO just give them the code? Please don't encourage these sorts of questions by providing the code dump.

Comment: @yshavit ok will not encourage

Comment: I had part of the code already. relax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use else condition to add the code for the numbers that are in the correct range, 100-999.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
int reverseInteger = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    int decimal = integer % 10;
    integer /= 10;
    reverseInteger *= 10;
    reverseInteger += decimal;
}
```

Put this right after the code that you wrote.

Answer (score -1):

If it's not cheating, this will work:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class StackOverflow {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StackOverflow so = new StackOverflow();
    so.go();

}

private void go() {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter an integer between 100-999: ");
    // int integer = in.nextInt();
    String input = in.next();
    in.close();
    StringBuilder reversed = new StringBuilder(input).reverse();
    int integer = 0;
    try {
        integer = Integer.parseInt(input);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, not an integer");
        return;
    }
    if (integer > 999) {
        System.out.print("Your number is not in the correct range, good bye");
    } else if (integer < 100) {
        System.out.print("Your number is not in the correct range, good bye");
    } else {

        // print reversed String
        System.out.format("\nYour input: %s", input);
        System.out.format("\nReversed: %s", reversed);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I can't use those types. only the ones I provided sadly